# How to completely remove flash from MacOSX?

Tags: macos, adobe-flash

I would like to get rid of flash completely on my MacOSX machine. I don't use it, and it's a danger. I've never been more happy than using http://clicktoflash.com/, but I've realized I don't use flash outside of a browser anyway. Is there a way I can remove it completely from the system to avoid net attacks where the browser may download a flash file and run it behind my back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete it from the "Internet Plugins" folder of /Library and ~/Library. Keep Google Chrome around, because it has Flash built in--you can keep it sandboxed.

You'll often find that, if videos are missing, they magically appear if you change your user agent string to Safari/iPad.  A lot of sites seem to keep their standards-based video streams reserved only for iPads.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe provides an [uninstaller](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/865/cpsid_86551.html#prob1=uninst).

Comment: Also, if you use Google Chrome or Chromium, you will have to go to `chrome://plugins` and disable Flash from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you lack the uninstaller, I find AppZapper a very handy utility to get rid of EVERYTHING related to an app (Library files, preferences, etc).